# How to create a ts object with a specific chosen time in python?

Tags: python, r, datetime, time-series

I am trying to translate this code from R to python, but I cannot create the time objects I want to work with. Here is an example of what I did in R.

```
## Subset to one observation per week on Mondays at 8:00pm for 2007, 2008 and 2009

house070809weekly <- filter(MultiYear1, weekdays == "monday" & hour == 20 & minute == 1)

## Create TS object with SubMeter3

tsSM3_070809weekly <- ts(house070809weekly$Sub_metering_3, frequency=52, start=c(2007,1))

## Plot sub-meter 3 with autoplot

autoplot(tsSM3_070809weekly)
```

```
             DateTime       Date     Time Sub_metering_1 Sub_metering_2 Sub_metering_3 year month week weekdays day hour minute
1  2006-12-16 17:24:00 2006-12-16 17:24:00              0              1             17 2006    12   50   sábado  16   17     24
2  2006-12-16 17:25:00 2006-12-16 17:25:00              0              1             16 2006    12   50   sábado  16   17     25
3  2006-12-16 17:26:00 2006-12-16 17:26:00              0              2             17 2006    12   50   sábado  16   17     26
4  2006-12-16 17:27:00 2006-12-16 17:27:00              0              1             17 2006    12   50   sábado  16   17     27
5  2006-12-16 17:28:00 2006-12-16 17:28:00              0              1             17 2006    12   50   sábado  16   17     28
6  2006-12-16 17:29:00 2006-12-16 17:29:00              0              2             17 2006    12   50   sábado  16   17     29
7  2006-12-16 17:30:00 2006-12-16 17:30:00              0              1             17 2006    12   50   sábado  16   17     30
8  2006-12-16 17:31:00 2006-12-16 17:31:00              0              1             17 2006    12   50   sábado  16   17     31
9  2006-12-16 17:32:00 2006-12-16 17:32:00              0              1             17 2006    12   50   sábado  16   17     32
10 2006-12-16 17:33:00 2006-12-16 17:33:00              0              2             16 2006    12   50   sábado  16   17     33
11 2006-12-16 17:34:00 2006-12-16 17:34:00              0              1             17 2006    12   50   sábado  16   17     34
12 2006-12-16 17:35:00 2006-12-16 17:35:00              0              1             17 2006    12   50   sábado  16   17     35
```

how can i filter the dates like that in python?

I tried something like this but I can't make it more specific as in R

```
# time series: consumption measured by kitchen submeter
ts = byDay["2009-09-01":].Sub_metering_1.copy()
# set index frequency as daily
ts = ts.asfreq("D")
# plot time series
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize= (14, 5))
ax = plt.plot(ts, linewidth= 0.75)
ax = plt.title("Daily energy consumption of kitchen")
```

Comment: In general you'll want to use a datetime data type to be able to filter easily. However the specifics depend on what you want to do further on, and what packages you want to use for that (vanilla Python, numpy, pandas, ...)

Answer (score 0):

I need to make a forecast of three ts.

```
H1W = data[(data['Weekday'] == 0)]
H1WH = H1W[(H1W['Hour'] == 20)]
H1WHM = H1WH[(H1WH['Minute'] == 1)]

byMonth1 = H1WHM.resample("M").fillna(method= "pad")
byWeek1 = H1WHM.resample("W").fillna(method= "pad")
byDay1 = H1WHM.resample("D").fillna(method= "pad")
byHour1 = H1WHM.resample("H").fillna(method= "pad")

ts = byDay1["2006-12-16":].Sub_metering_3.copy()
ts = ts.asfreq("D")

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize= (14, 5))
ax = plt.plot(ts, 'tab:green', linewidth= 0.75)
ax = plt.title("Sub-meter 3 one observation per week on Mondays at 8:00pm for each year")
```

It seems to work, but it doesn't look very good to me, and I need to figure out how I can do the forecast.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).